# replace 'Null' with zero in python

Tags: python, django

I'm replacing `Null` or `None` with zero when there is a value I want to show the value in Django Even when there is a value for the `'Requester'` in SQL it still showing as zero.

In SQL, I'm getting `'Requester'` value as `5` but still it's showing as 0. I don't know where I'm going wrong

Here, what I tried

```
@apiview(['GET'])
def GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit(UserID):
   if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set =cursor.fetchall()
       
        IsActive = 'true'
        data = []
        for row in result_set:
         
            TaskId = row[0]
            data.append({
            'TaskId':row[0],           
            'TaskName' : row[1],
            'Source' : row[2],        
            'Requester' : 0 if row[3] == 'NULL' or 'NONE' else row[3],
            'type' : row[4],    
            })
            return Response(data[0], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: `0 if row[3] == 'NULL' or row[3] == 'NONE' else row[3],`

Comment: Its showing as `null` rather than showing as zero

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem better yet `0 if row[3] in ['NULL', 'NONE']  else row[3],`

Comment: @kelvin003: likely due to uppercase/lowercase. `0 if row[3].casefold() == 'null' or row[3].casefold() == 'none' else row[3],`

Comment: Still I'm getting as `null` rather than showing as zero. In my database 'Requester' value is 'NULL' but in Django I want to show it up as zero @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @kelvin003: ah, it is `NULL` in the database, then it is `0 if row[3] is None else row[3]`.